# Inserting data from multiple file sources into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, bulkinsert

I can insert .txt data into SQL using `Bulk Insert`, but how can I add data from multiple sources into same table using a query?

Comment: MySQL Community Server or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: You can try loading everything into separate staging tables on the same server, then move/merge the data where it needs to go.  Another option is to use a tool like SSIS to better manage the flow of your data over multiple sources.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server it is

Answer (score 1):

You can string them together in a stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE LoadAll AS
BULK INSERT mytable
FROM 'C:\file1.txt'

BULK INSERT mytable
FROM 'C:\file2.txt'

BULK INSERT mytable
FROM 'C:\file3.txt'
GO
```